# Python Parsing Framework

Tags: python, data-mining, text-parsing

If I needed facilitate the extraction of data from various (non-API) internet sources, is there a framework-type solution that would streamline the process of having developers write reusable, yet source specific parsers on a large scale?

Comment: Do you need to parse the HTML?

Comment: yes, in some instances but it would be text as well, so a straight html parser wouldn't be a complete solution - Ideally it would be similar to a html template engine but in the reverse - so you would have tags like: high tide: {{ time }} but could also work with html, and more complex things like loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is a Python library that I've found to be very useful for parsing custom domain specific languages.

Answer (score 0):

For *ML screen scraping, look no further than [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).